# MySQL query to delete all the random data between two known strings

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQl Database, the table name is "post_data" field name is "content_data"

I want to delete all the random data between two known strings.

i want to delete all text between 'www.OldDomain.com/' & '/www.NewDomian.com'

For example:
www.OldDomain.com/redirect?RandomTextUrl/www.NewDomian.com/txturl

any suggestion will be appreciated?

Comment: www.OldDomain.com/redirect?RandomTextUrl/www.NewDomian.com/txturl what should become?

Comment: did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of these strings appears exactly once in `content_data` and in the correct order:

```
select concat(substring_index(content_data, 'www.OldDomain.com', 1),
              'www.OldDomain.com',
              'www.NewDomian.com',
              substring_index(content_data, 'www.NewDomian.com', -1)
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to struggle and do it using MySQL You could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://coderwall.com/p/zzgo-w/splitting-strings-with-mysql)

I would suggest to use PHP/Java/C# or any other language to do these kinds of string parsing though.

Comment: actually my target is to clean the database no only control the output. thanks

Comment: I understand. You could use the substring_index inside an UPDATE command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOCATE` and `SUBSTRING` functions to get the string between two desired strings.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
  data,
  LOCATE('www.OldDomain.com/', data) + LENGTH('www.OldDomain.com/'),
  LOCATE('/www.NewDomain.com', data) - (LOCATE('www.OldDomain.com/', data) + LENGTH('www.OldDomain.com/'))
  ) as output
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

NOTE: `TABLE_NAME` is your table name, `data` is your column name and `output` is the alias for the extracted data.

Sample Run

```
CREATE TABLE stack (data varchar(100));
INSERT INTO stack VALUES('www.OldDomain.com/redirect?RandomTextUrl/www.NewDomain.com/txturl');
INSERT INTO stack VALUES('BEFOREwww.OldDomain.com/redirect?RandomTextUrl/www.NewDomain.com/txturl');
INSERT INTO stack VALUES('www.OldDomain.com/redirect?RandomTextUrl/www.NewDomain.com/txturlAFTER');
```

[image]